# In PowerBI, how to expand row values in a matrix and keep showing subtotals

Tags: matrix, powerbi

In Power BI, I have the next problem. I have a matrix with subtotals and I want to expand one of the subtotals and continue seeing the value of the rest subtotals, but they disappear when I expand one of the subtotals. How can I do to continue showing those values?

[Original Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBZEc.png)

[Expanded Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9fR3.png)

I have highlighted in yellow where I would like to continue seeing the subtotal (like in the original matrix when it wasn't expanded).

PS: I have the option Row Subtotals On

Thanks!

Comment: Your requirement (with Row Subtotals On) is the standard behavior of a matrix. Did you made any other adjustments? Please provide some sample data if possible.